# How can I remove a cell from a TiledMap in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, layer

I have this file and I want to remove the numbers "31" and "32" from my map.

https://mega.nz/#!o7xDGKiS!K90BfxBiaRNVMkY9SPox8bRNm3rwNPjbQcaEC3wSGjM

How can I do this? I tried with:

```
TiledMapTileLayer tile = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0);
tile.getCell(y,layer).setTile(null);
```

but doesn't work well. Can someone help me?

Comment: What you mean on `doesn't work well` ? Are you removing other tile or nothing happens?

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks.